# Join tables in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have 3 tables in my sqllite database 
Two are config tables and one is main table where my data is stored.
now how to retrive data from main table by joining 2 tables in android, How and where to perform join operations.

Can anyone guide me.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp check this one and use different  type joins as per your requirements....

Comment: Thanks for your response SBJ actually I am aware of these joins but I am not sure how to perform the same in android

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can just execute a rawQuery.
For example something like this:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT a.* 
FROM table_1 a 
INNER JOIN table_2 b ON a.id=b.anyId 
INNER JOIN table_3 c ON b.id= c.anyId
WHERE c.key = ?", new String[]{"test"});
```

The first parameter is the query you want to execute. For all your keys you want to add to your query just add an `?` in the query.
The second parameter is a String Array. In this array you put your keys, like the example  given above the value `test`.

**EDIT:**

it's also possible to use rawQuery for `update`, `insert` or `delete`.
For example one simple update query:

```
db.rawQuery("UPDATE table_1
SET fieldA = ?,
fieldB = ?
WHERE id = ?", new String[]{"test", "test2", "1"});
```

Comment: Thanks Obl Tobl but I learned raw query may create some problems is there any other way to perform join and fire select query

Comment: Can you tell me which problems you heard about? i never had any problems in my projects.

Comment: Often raw query method returns wrong results and i was advised not to use it... If it is the valid way can we perform insert, update and delete as well with raw query... If yes can you please guide me. sorry for asking somany question I am a newbie in android and I am just learning stage.. Thanks

Comment: if your query isn't wrong, the results from rawQuery also won't be wrong. Why do you want to insert, update or delete with raw Query? There are other methods for that.

Comment: Yes I agree there are other methods but I personally feel it is easy to write SQL query that using the predefined process also I am good at writing general SQL statements... Please can you give me insert, update and delete for a raw query

Comment: Maybe you just read my answer once again. Then maybe you can imagine how it works, not only with select, but also with insert, update and delete. There is everything explained what you will need.

Answer (score 0):

class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper

write below code in your funcions...

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    private final String MY_QUERY = "YOUR QUERY";

    db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, new String[]{"Parameter"});
    db.close();
```

Comment: Thanks SBJ will implement it.

Comment: you really just copy my answer? that's not really gentleman style...

Comment: i copy your query purpose how to use query... now i deleted ok ....

Answer (score -1):

You need [rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) method for solve this issue.

```
private final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM table_a a INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.id=b.other_id WHERE b.property_id=?";

db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, new String[]{String.valueOf(propertyId)});
```

But if you want to do a good implementation create a SQLiteHelper and DataSource for each table and do the relationship in the datasource.

Comment: Thanks for your response <br/>Yes..exactly... instead of this raw query just like insert is there any fucntion to join tables and use in our select query